# Como logro que el id de un campo en mi BD coincida con el valor de un select option y a su vez si cambio de option tome el valor que este muestra

Tags: php, html, sql

Hola llevo 3 semanas intentando lograr esto y no he podido obtener resultados, estoy realizando una actualización de los datos personales independendientes de un usuario ya logueado, yo tengo una tabla llamada persona en esta tabla se encuentran los registros ya existentes que quiero actualizar, en esta misma tabla tengo campos como; IdEstadoCivil, IdSexo, Nacimiento y estos campos almacenan solo el ID del nombre de elemento que almacena.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor manera de hacerlo es a partir de un `foreach` y ya sea que los datos lleguen mediante ajax, los consultes directo o bien uses POO con DAO para obtenerlos, la idea es simple, el flujo es el siguiente.

```
Obtencion de datos -> acceso a datos desde la vista -> iteracion sobre cada valor del select -> asignación de ID y leyenda
```

Tomando eso en cuenta se puede hacer de varia maneras, en este caso te muestro un codigo que puedes implementar y cambiar.

Esto es suponiendo que todo lo vas a hacer en el mismo archivo `algo.php` aunque lo mejor seria separarlo.

```
<?php
   $query = "SELECT id,name FROM table";
   $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
   $stmt->execute();
   $valores = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   $stmt->close(); 
   if(!$valores){
      /*MENSAJE DE ERROR AL OBTENER LOS DATOS*/
   }
?>

<!--Interpretar valores dentro del select-->
<SELECT name="someName">
    <?php foreach($valores as $v):?> 
        <option value="<?php echo $v['id'];?>"><?php echo $v['name'];?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</SELECT>
```

Con esto estas logrando que tu `SELECT` se llene con valores de tu BD sin ingresarlos de forma manual, de aqui lo que seguiria seria enviarlo mediante tu formulario y cacharlo desde el backend, otra forma de hacerlo es en el mismo documento, sin embargo al final es basicamente el mismo codigo.

```
<?php
   if(!ISSET($_POST['someName']) || $_POST['someName'] == NULL){
      /*Los valores no estan llegando*/
   }
   $valor = $_POST["someName"];
   //Por seguridad siempre se revisa que exista el dato y eso se hace se la siguiente manera 
   $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?";
   $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
   $stmt->bind_params("s",$valor);
   $stmt->execute();
   $result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
   $stmt->close();
   if(!$result){
       /*EL VALOR DE LLEGA ES INCORRECTO*/
   }
?>
```

Una vez que has hecho eso puedes escalarlo y llevarlo a otras formas, te recomiendo que leas los siguientes enlaces para que puedas entender mas como es que esto se maneja.

### Enlaces a fuentes externas

[LLENAR UN SELECT MEDIANTE AJAX CON PHP Y JQUERY USANDO JSON](https://anexsoft.com/llenar-un-select-mediante-ajax-con-php-y-jquery-usando-json)

[Mysqli SELECT query with prepared statements](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/prepared_select)

[Clases y objetos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.php)

Comment: ¿Entonces estos dos ejemplos que me has mostrado sirven para taer los valores si tener que meterlos manualmente como yo lo hice en  mi formulario? así lo entendi

Comment: El primer segmento de codigo es para eso que tú dices, el segundo va para cuando mandas el formulario y debes recoger el dato seleccionado, hay otro más que me deje de largo que es dejar seleccionado el que el usuario tenga asignado